# Django app on Elastic Beanstalk can't connect to RDS

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, rds

I have a Django app running on Elastic Beanstalk that is throwing the following error:

```
[:error] [pid 12271] (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)")
```

I have no issue connecting to the EB server via ssh and then connecting to MySql:

```
mysql -uadmin -p -hxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

So I've ruled out that its a firewall issue, or problems with my VPC.  I've also tried hardcoding the credentials in the settings.py file to rule out issues with the ENV vars.  I don't know much about Django so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing some packages for my .ebextensions, I added:

```
packages:
  yum:
    gcc: []
    mysql: []
    mysql-devel: []
    python-devel: []
```